# nodejs - run a function at a specific time

Tags: node.js, timer

I'm building a website that some users will enter and after a specific amount of time an algorithm has to run in order to take the input of the users that is stored in the database and create some results for them storing the results also in the database. The problem is that in nodejs i cant figure out where and how should i implement this algorithm in order to run after a specific amount of time and only once(every few minutes or seconds).
The app is builded in nodejs-expressjs.
For example lets say that i start the application and after 3 minutes the algorithm should run and take some data from the database and after the algorithm has created some output stores it in database again.
What are the typical solutions for that (at least one is enough). thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, but this might be what you're looking for: [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron)

Comment: Perhaps you just want `setTimeout()` which lets you schedule a function to be called at a time you specify in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it's not clear whether you want to run the algorithm on the web server (perhaps processing input from multiple users) or on the client (processing the input from a particular user).

If the former, then use setTimeout(), or something similar, in your main javascript file that creates the web server listener.  Your server can then be handling inputs from users (via the app listener) and in parallel running algorithms that look at the database.

If the latter, then use setTimeout(), or something similar, in the javascript code that is being loaded into the user's browser.

You may actually need some combination of the above: code running on the server to periodically do some processing on a central database, and code running in each user's browser to periodically refresh the user's display with new data pulled down from the server.

You might also want to implement a websocket and json rpc interface between the client and the server. Then, rather than having the client "poll" the server for the results of your algorithm, you can have the client listen for events arriving on the websocket.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, i want to run the algorithm on the server after a specific period when the user has sent me his/her input. Exactly as you describe it in the 4th paragraph of your answer. My problem back then was, that i could not understand how could i start execute this periodical algorithm. I did not wanted to start this periodical algorithm when the app was starting cause there where no users then. I wanted to run it when after a specific amount of users had entered on the app, something like a small game. Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have a user request that saves url to crawl and get listed products

So one of the simplest ways would be to:
On user requests create in DB "tasks" table

userId | urlToCrawl | dateAdded | isProcessing | ....

Then in node main site you have some setInterval(findAndProcessNewTasks, 60000) 
so it will get all  tasks that are not currently in work (where isProcessing is false)
every 1 min or whatever interval you need

**findAndProcessNewTasks**
will query db and run your algorithm for every record that is not processed yet
also it will set isProcessing to true
eventually once algorithm is finished it will remove the record from tasks (or mark some another field like "finished" as true)

Depending on load and number of tasks it may make sense to process your algorithm in another node app

Typically you would have a message bus (Kafka, rabbitmq etc.) with main app just sending events and worker node.js apps doing actual job and inserting products into db

this would make main app lightweight and allow scaling worker apps

Comment: yes, but my problem is that i dont know i which file should i put the setInterval or setTimeout function, because in nodejs - express, a file runs everytime that a user makes a request (i hope my hypothesis is not wrong) so if i put it for example in a route, the function setInterval will run and call the algorithm as much as the requests of the users in that route, of course i can have a hidden route just only me will know but i dont want to do it manually, i want to get initialized/scheduled when the app starts and be called only once.

Comment: You don't need set interval on each request. 
you need only one in the main index.js file (or whatever is executed and calls app.listen() )

so every time it will be checking for new tasks and run them all at once. 

if the time when it needs to be run is different instead of "dateAdded" rely on some "dateToExecute" field that will contain computed time 

so timer will be created once, will run with N sec interval and constantly checks if there are any tasks to execute

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly - I would just send the data to the client-side while rendering the page and store it into some hidden tag (like input type="hidden"). Then I would run a script on the server-side with setTimeout to display the data to the client.